# Moving gameobject based on direction but the movement gets effected by distance of cursor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a peice of code that instantiates a gameobject, set its rotation to face  the direction of the cursor from the player character at that moment and move towards that direction with constant speed for 2 seconds then stop. However my piece of coded is moving the gameobject towards the cursor direction but the speed gets changed depending on how far my cursor is from the player character.

```cs
private IEnumerator Rake()
{
    Vector3 relativepos = 
        Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativepos, Vector3.up);
    float timepassed = 0;
    GameObject WcastRB = 
        Instantiate(Wcast, gameObject.transform.position, rotation);

    Rigidbody2D rg;
    rg = WcastRB.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    while (timepassed < 2)
    {
        timepassed += Time.deltaTime;
        rg.velocity = WcastRB.transform.forward * 1000 * Time.deltaTime;

        if (timepassed >= 2)
        {
            rg.velocity = WcastRB.transform.forward * 0;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

this is what I have made.

Comment: Consider [normalizing the `relativepos`.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Normalize.html) so distance doesn't affect the velocity.

Comment: im not using the `relativepos` as the multiple of the speed, it is only used to set the rotation of the instantiated object and im using `transform.forward` to set the speed of the object, i tried to normalize the `relativepos` but it the problem is still there

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, I found that because `transform.forward` was dependent on the object's rotation(and subsequently the original click position).

When the click was too close to the object the `transform.forward` `Vector2` had a magnitude(length) of less than one, causing the speed to slow down.

By increasing the magnitude of the velocity to exactly `1f` it should go consistent speeds in all directions

```cs
IEnumerator Rake()
{

    Vector3 relativepos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativepos, Vector3.up);

    float timepassed = 0;
    GameObject WcastRB = Instantiate(Wcast, gameObject.transform.position, rotation);
    Rigidbody2D rg;

    rg = WcastRB.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    Vector2 velocity = rg.transform.forward;

    velocity.Normalize();

    while (timepassed < 2)
    {
        timepassed += Time.deltaTime;

        rg.velocity = velocity * 1000 * Time.deltaTime;

        if (timepassed >= 2)
        {
            rg.velocity = new Vector2();
        }

        yield return null;

    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Removed self-implemented `.Normalize()` because I forgot that i also used the built in `.Normalize()` *literally right before it*.

Comment: Why do you nest the method within the IEnumerator? Also I think the modifier is not needed .. after calling Normalize the magnitude will be `1` amyway

Comment: Also note that it is not `rg.transform.forward` what OP is using bit rather `WcastRB.transform.forward` ;)

Comment: `IncreaseMagnitude` is tightly coupled with `IEnumerator Rake()`, by using a local method, It avoids abstracting what the `IncreaseMagnitude` method does and increases the readability of the code. It's important to note that the compiler doesn't care where the method is defined since it's not an actual object, it wont be re-defined every time `IEnumerator Rake()` begins it's coroutine so it purely syntactic.

Comment: `rg.transform.forward` is an inherited member of `GameObject`. I guess you could save a couple cycles by using `WcastRB.transform.forward`, but they're both referencing the same property.

Comment: Oh yeah didn't see that `rg` was set there. Instead of the local method I would claim though it is better readable if you simply assign it directly without a method ;)

Comment: You're totally right, but I just re-read your first comment you were right though, I completely forgot that I normalized the value, then i re normalized it right after with a self-implemented normalization lmao